# How could I improve my question about installing py modules?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I have done [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515844/cant-pip-install-numpy-with-a-python-3-9-venv), that received many downvotes without explaining. Why is it a bad question?

The only explanation I found is that it's not strictly related to programming; but SO is full of question to how to install libraries - modules - packages.

Can you give me your opinion and feedback?

Comment: For starters, please stop misusing inline code formatting for things that are not code. Names of products and languages, like Python, are not code, and therefore should not be formatted as such.

Comment: @CodyGray: Ah ok. It was only to make them more explicit. Maybe I can use italic style?

Comment: @CodyGray: anyway I don't think it was downvoted for this reason, I (mis) used this style in all my question and answers before :-)

Comment: Code formatting is for code, not emphasis. It actually makes things more difficult to read. I don’t think italics is appropriate, either. The name Python doesn’t need to be emphasized. The question is already tagged appropriately, and if it isn’t clear after reading the question that you’re talking about Python, something else is badly wrong. No, I don’t suspect this is why you were downvoted, which is why I didn’t post it as a proper answer. (Although I have personally downvoted many posts for precisely this reason.)

Comment: @CodyGray: Oook... probably I have this vice because I usually have the habit of empathize the program languages and libraries I used in my CV :-D

Comment: I hate to be argumentative (no, I really don’t), but you probably shouldn’t use code formatting for names of programming languages/tools on your CV, either.